# ruby could not find valid gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I have been trying to develop a Ruby on Rails app but cannot.  I have unistalled and reinstalled and it keeps saying cert not found even though I can see the cert on my computer.

```
C:\DevKit>gem install json --platform=ruby
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
C:\DevKit>gem install json -- platform=ruby2.2
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
RubyGems 2.3.0 installed
RubyGems installed the following executables:
    C:/Ruby22/bin/gem

C:\>cd devkit
C:\DevKit>cd assignment_10
C:\DevKit\Assignment_10>cd C:\DevKit\Assignment_10
C:\DevKit\Assignment_10>cd ..
C:\DevKit>gem install json --platform=ruby
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
C:\DevKit>gem install bson_ext --platform=ruby
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bson_ext' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
C:\DevKit>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just get it from http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Rails on windows, I suggest you to look at this installer which is pretty great : [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/)